# cannot locate node joy

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, joy-node, joystick, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Hydro on Precise. Following the tutorials on joystick operation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode). The joystick works, roscore is running, joy_node is running, when I do rostopic echo joy I see the vectors change as I expect when the joystick controls are moved. When I run roslaunch learning_joy turtle_joy.launch however, the joystick still works, topic echo shows still sending, but no movement of the turtle. The error message is as follows:

```
roslaunch learning_joy turtle_joy.launch
... logging to /home/richard/.ros/log/3b2f6bb6-e9cc-11e3-811a-00215c98e435/roslaunch-inga-12328.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://inga:38218/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /axis_angular
 * /axis_linear
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /scale_angular
 * /scale_linear
 * /turtle_joy/deadzone
 * /turtle_joy/dev

NODES
  /
    sim (turtlesim/turtlesim_node)
    teleop (turtle_teleop/turtle_teleop_joy)
    turtle_joy (joy/joy)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[sim-1]: started with pid [12346]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [joy/joy]: can't locate node [joy] in package [joy]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtle_teleop/turtle_teleop_joy]: turtle_teleop
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/richard/catkin_ws/my_src
ROS path [2]=/home/richard/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
```

A search of ROS answers (unless I missed something) yields nothing that I haven't already tried. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172503/cannot-locate-node-joy/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It must be of type "joy_node" not "joy".
I mean in ur launch file
u have

```
<!-- joy node -->


<node respawn="true" pkg="joy"
        type="joy" name="turtle_joy" >
    <param name="dev" type="string" value="/dev/input/js0" />
    <param name="deadzone" value="0.12" />
  </node>
```

It must be

```
<!-- joy node -->
  <node respawn="true" pkg="joy"
        type="joy_node" name="turtle_joy" >
    <param name="dev" type="string" value="/dev/input/js0" />
    <param name="deadzone" value="0.12" />
  </node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Dpp_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/18691/dpp_coder/) with karma: 60 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on 2014-06-08**:
No joy. Changed joy to joy_node, still exactly the same problem.

**Comment by [Dpp_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/18691/dpp_coder/) on 2014-06-08**:
The error is it exactly the same??

**Comment by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on 2014-06-08**:
see above, just added the new screenshot, should I have made that a comment?

**Comment by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on 2014-06-08**:
Actually, now that you mention it, it now finds joy, but still can't launch turtle_teleop_joy. I had posted the error here, but figured I'd better start a new thread as your fix did indeed correct the subject line problem.. Thanks for the help!